# Iphone Client Managing multiple responses at a time using tcp sockets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sockets, tcp

I am creating an iphone application, the application will use tcp sockets for server side communication, now in my case i will be listening the server using a socket for server side response, and there can be multiple responses in json format at a time which will needed to be displayed in a table view, now i am confused how to cater (parsing response and displaying data) multiple responses at a time, should i use a thread for each incoming response, or use a mutex lock type strategy, so that first response catered first time then the next one, plz. guide, any example with code can be very helpful. thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about this too much. You will know which socket the response was received on - this gives you the context for each bit of data you receive.

Comment: can u plz. explain a little more, i mean i will have a delegate like this with enum- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent , NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable, and they will cater only one response at a time??? this is what you mean?

Comment: Exactly, the first parameter is the stream for which this event occurred - so you can use this to know what do to